Bootloader failed to install on my external SSD
I have Kingston external SSD of 512 GB. Out of which 406GB is NTFS which I use to store movies, games and another important stuff. And Partition 2 is an extended partition of 70 GB. (I have attached a screenshot of partition). 
Here extended partition is /dev/sda2
I tried to install different Linux distros but every time bootloader fails to install.
While installing I create manual partition

EFI (300mb) with mount point /boot/efi and label as efi. This is /dev/sda5
/ (remaining) with mount point / and label as root. This is /dev/sda6

The installation is successful but then it shows that "Bootloader failed to install will not be able to boot in your system". Here is the error thar Manjaro gave.
2024-08-23 - 18:59:16 [6]: [PYTHON JOB]: Found gettext "en" in "/usr/share/locale/en" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:16 [6]:     .. Job description from pretty_name "bootloader" = "Install bootloader." 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:16 [6]: [PYTHON JOB]: "Bootloader: grub (efi)" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:16 [6]:     .. Running ("grub-install", "--target=x86_64-efi", "--efi-directory=/boot/efi", "--bootloader-id=Manjaro", "--force") 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]:     .. Target cmd: ("grub-install", "--target=x86_64-efi", "--efi-directory=/boot/efi", "--bootloader-id=Manjaro", "--force") Exit code: 1 output:
 Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: Function not implemented
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [2]: WARNING: [PYTHON JOB]: "Command 'grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Manjaro --force' returned non-zero exit status 1." 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: [PYTHON JOB]: "stdout:Installing for x86_64-efi platform.\nCould not prepare Boot variable: Function not implemented\ngrub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error." 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: [PYTHON JOB]: "stderr:None" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: virtual void Calamares::JobThread::run()
    Skipping non-emergency job "postcfg" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]:     ..  Skipping non-emergency job "Unmount file systems." 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [1]: void Calamares::ViewManager::onInstallationFailed(const QString&, const QString&)
    ERROR: Installation failed: "Bootloader installation error" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]:     .. - message: "Bootloader installation error" 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]:     .. - details: The bootloader could not be installed. The installation command <pre>grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Manjaro --force</pre> returned error code 1.
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: void Calamares::ViewManager::onInstallationFailed(const QString&, const QString&)
    Calamares will quit when the dialog closes. 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: void Config::doNotify(bool, bool)
    Notification not sent; completion: failed 
2024-08-23 - 18:59:18 [6]: void {anonymous}::PowerManagementInterface::uninhibitSleep()
    Sleep was never inhibited. 

Here is the full error log https://termbin.com/4u57
Then I went in BIOS of my computer and tried to manually create point by selecting My SSD name -> OEM -> EFI -> Manjaro/Fedora  -> .efi file. (Manjaro/Fedora because I tried for both of them). And when I open that that bootpoint it opens "Minimal Bash line editing". So i performed few steps from Geeks-For-Geeks website

set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix= (hd0, msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal

But it didn't boot, because, of course,  I didn't knew what I was doing.
Currently, I have Fedora installed on this extended partition. I am posting this on here because the error is same on all distros and the community of AskUbuntu is large. Fedora didn't show the error log but it only showed
The following error occurred while installing the the boot loader. 
The system wilt not be bootable. Would you like to ignore this and continue with installation?

Failed to set new efi boot target. This is most likely kernel or firmware bug.

One last thing I need to say is that, I don't want my Windows boot manager to change or remove (If it's possible for my setup). I need a solution where Fedora only loads when my External SSD is attached, if its not then Windows should boot like it does for every normal user.

Most Linux installs allow the very, very old MBR(msdos) partitioning and UEFI boot. They probably should not. Windows has required gpt partitioning for UEFI boot since 2012, so all drives should be gpt. But conversion from MBR to gpt totally erases drive, so good backups required if converting. Systems starting in 2020 now are UEFI only, so they not may like MBR partitions. Or maybe just not logical partitions. Typically ESP is one of first partitions in any drive. I might try making it a primary partition as first test.

Your ntfs partition is not a Windows boot, you have enough free space at the end of device for a backup gpt partition table, so the conversion msdos to gpt may be trivial -- so trivial I didn't even write it into my notes when I did it. Probably used the gdisk conversion. The ubuntu partitions were untouched. I did have to reinstall Windows on that disk over the old install, and it did make another EFI partition, but things went pretty smoothly. Backup everything first, just in case. But not an Ubuntu problem, so voting to close.

So it means that my external SSD has MBR partition table, and that is what is causing the problem?

In that case I will surely need to format my SSD. In the NTFS partition of 406 GB I have a game of 251 GB. Is there a way to convert MBR to GPT without losing data?
